# Misunderstanding Dynamic Binding

Tags: java, inheritance, dynamic, binding

From what I understand about dynamic binding, the JVM, at runtime, looks at the actual type of an object and searches for an implementation in that class and works its way up through the inheritance levels.

For example if we have: `Vehicle v = new Car();`

Assuming that the class `Car` extends `Vehicle`, we can see that the reference variable type is Vehicle and the object type is Car.

If we were to say: `v.start()`:

The JVM would look for the start method implementation first in the Car class and then in the Vehicle class.

An example of this is in this code:

```
public class scratch{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Vehicle v = new Car(); 
        v.start(); 
    }
}

class Vehicle{
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Vehicle class"); 
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle{
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car class"); 
    }
}
```

The output of this code, as expected is: "Car class"

This is my question: If I take out the start method from class Vehicle, completely erase it, the program won't run anymore. From what I understand about dynamic binding, the JVM should still look at the actual type of the object (which in this case is Car) and still run the car implementation of the start method. However, it does not do this.

Why?

Comment: Because the method doesn't exist.  You'll get a [NoSuchMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)

Comment: IMHO if you remove the `start` function and do `Vehicle v = new Car()` it would be a compiler error. Since the compiler checks the LHS object to verify if the functions called exists in it or not.

Comment: @VusP it depends on if he modified the .class or the .java. But yeah, a compile error is more likely.

Comment: @tieTYT maybe i misunderstood "If I take out the start method from class Vehicle, completely erase it". What does he mean by that?

Comment: @VusP I think it's ambiguous.  We both interpreted it different ways :) But it doesn't prevent us from answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with removing `start()` from `Vehicle` has to do with polymorphism.  In `Vehicle`, if you define `start()` here, then that is what says that all `Vehicle`s, even subclasses, have that method.

If you remove `start()` from `Vehicle()`, then it can't be guaranteed that any `Vehicle` has a `start()` method, even though we know it's a `Car` that does have `start()`.  What if there is a `HorselessCarriage` class that extends `Vehicle` but doesn't define `start()`?  Then, there is no `start()` method.  For that reason, if there's no `start()` method on `Vehicle`, you can't call `start()` on a `Vehicle` variable.

The whole point of being able to call `start()` on a `Vehicle` is to ensure that *any* `Vehicle` implementation has a `start()` method to call.

**UPDATE**

The JVM takes the runtime type of the object and looks for a method matching the signature of the method call.  If not found, it walks up the inheritance tree to the superclass and looks for the method there.

More details are given in the [JLS, Section 15.12.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.4):

> Let X be the compile-time type of the target reference of the method
>   invocation. Then:
>
> If class S contains a declaration for a non-abstract method named m
>   with the same descriptor (same number of parameters, the same
>   parameter types, and the same return type) required by the method
>   invocation as determined at compile time (§15.12.3), then:
>
> If the invocation mode is super or interface, then this is the method
>   to be invoked, and the procedure terminates.
>
> If the invocation mode is virtual, and the declaration in S overrides
>   (§8.4.8.1) X.m, then the method declared in S is the method to be
>   invoked, and the procedure terminates.
>
> If the invocation mode is virtual, and the declaration in S does not
>   override X.m, and moreover X.m is declared abstract, then an
>   AbstractMethodError is thrown.
>
> Otherwise, if S has a superclass, this same lookup procedure is
>   performed recursively using the direct superclass of S in place of S;
>   the method to be invoked is the result of the recursive invocation of
>   this lookup procedure.

Here, `S` appears to be the runtime type of the object.

Comment: This makes sense and I suspected it even before writing this question. But then I have to ask, how does dynamic binding exactly work? When deciding what method to call, where does the JVM start?

Comment: @rgettman Thanks for confirming. This is how I thought it worked but had yet to look up!

Answer (score 1):

In nutshell, `JVM` need one endpoint to begin the search for the reference of the `start` method, not matter the object type have a method that you want to invoke, `JVM` need a mirror to ensure you are  trying to call an existing method.

Comment: I don't exactly understand. What is the endpoint that the JVM chooses in this instance? Also, what do you mean by mirror?

Comment: The dynamic linking must have a point where to start and find the appropriate reference to the method in the [virtual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), so that if you try to access a method that does not exist in this variable simply the JVM  did not pass the compilation face, because not this variable does not have this  method.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the start() method in the Vehicle class, Car is Overriding that method. When you remove the start() method from Vehicle, you are no longer overriding that method.  So calling v.start() has no method to call.  This is why you should use @Override, so that it is clear in the code what is happening.  In order to call start() on Car in the case where there is no start() method in Vehicle, you'd first have to cast the vehicle to the Car class.

Comment: I'm going to reply the same way I did on rgettman's comment. This makes sense and I expected this, but then, at runtime, which class does the JVM start at when deciding which method implementation to run?

Comment: At runtime, I think it starts with the class of the actual object.  So in this case it would start by looking at Car.

Answer (score 0):

But once you remove the method, Vehicle no longer has any "start" functionality: it is an unknown method in the Vehicle class, and you are accessing it through a Vehicle reference.  To make java do what you want, you could do

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
  public abstract void start();
}
```

Your code should then work again, because all children of Vehicle are now guaranteed a start method.  But as it stands in your example, once the start method is removed, there's no guarantee that some previous statement hasn't created some other Vehicle descendant, e.g.,  Motorcycle without a start method and assigned it to your v reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way to see the problem is to introduce a method.  Here's how the method is defined:

```
public void callStart(Vehicle vehicle) {
  vehicle.start();
}
```

This method lets you pass in a concrete `Car` or a concrete `Vehicle`.

Lets pretend that Java lets you compile this code.  *If* Java let you do this for a `Vehicle` without a `start()` method, then you'd have to discover the error at runtime.  But Java saves you some time by letting you know when you've compile that you have an error.

This is different from some dynamic languages like Javascript.  If this were JavaScript you could pass in a concrete `Vehicle` and then you'd have to discover your error at runtime.  Another difference is that in JavaScript, you could pass in a concrete `Car` and it would work without error.  This is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and is a feature Java doesn't have.